# Binary search tree, only 'duplicates' alert printed out for recursive insertion - C++

Tags: c++, recursion, insert, binary-tree

I'm still pretty new with BSTs and I'm trying to write a recursive insert node method, using a private one that calls the public method. I've been trying to debug what my issue may be but for all the values I've tried to insert, I get an infinite sequence of alert messages instead saying I cant insert duplicates. What am I doing wrong?

Insert function:

```
template <class T>
void Bst<T>::insertNode(nodeType<T>* &p, const T& insertItem)
{

    if(p == nullptr)
    {
        nodeType<T> *newNode;
        newNode = new nodeType<T>;
        newNode->info = insertItem;
        newNode->lLink = nullptr;
        newNode->rLink = nullptr;
        p = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        if(p->info == insertItem)
        {

            cout << "Insert failed: No duplicates allowed." << endl;

        }
        else if(p->info > insertItem)
        {
            return insertNode(p->lLink, insertItem);
        }
        else
            return insertNode(p->rLink, insertItem);
    }

}
```

Public method:

```
template <class T>
void Bst<T>::insertNodeRecursive(const T& insertItem)
{
    insertNode(root, insertItem);
}
```

Main method where I use it:

```
void readTree(Vector<WindLogType> &windlog){

    Bst<Date> dateTree;

    for(int x = 1; x < windlog.vecsize(); x++)
    {
        dateTree.insertNodeRecursive(windlog[x].d);
    }

    dateTree.inOrderTraversal();

}
```

`operator==` overload to compare date values:

```
bool operator==(const Date& firstDate, const Date& secondDate)
{
    if(firstDate.GetYear() == secondDate.GetYear() && firstDate.GetMonth() == secondDate.GetMonth() && firstDate.GetDay() == secondDate.GetDay())
    {

        return true;

    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

If anymore code is needed let me know, also my default constructor sets my 'dateTree' root node to nullptr.

Comment: Possibly a bug in `operator==` for `Date`? I don't see anything much wrong with `insertNode`.

Comment: Using a debugger would be the best way to sort this out.

Comment: @john After using my debugger, I can see that my `insertItem` is always the same date value, which is the very first date value in my input file. So im assuming that thats probably why it is always calling duplicate condition. However, I know it cant be anything wrong with my input methods for the file because they worked perfectly fine when I was using an iterative insert method. Also, I have included my `operator==` overload .

Comment: Well nothing wrong with operator== (apart from `if (X) return true; else return false;`, is more simply written as `return X;`) so I would say the problem is with your input routines, or with the way that the input routine is passing information to the insertNode routine. I don't think the bug is in any of the code you have posted so far. When bug hunting try not to assume too much. The very fact that you have a bug means that somewhere one of your assumptions is wrong. How about posting the input routine and the code that calls the `readTree` routine.

Comment: OK I see what you are saying. My input routine is pretty large, is there somewhere else I can post the entire code? I was just thinking that it cant possibly be something wrong with my input routines because I have other methods for different operations that need all the values from the files and I can access them with no issue, but this readTree method's insertItem is always the first date only for some reason. I'm happy to post my code somewhere but it would be too large for here

Comment: Well probably easier, and more instructive for you, would be to fire up the debugger again. Track the dates as they're being read and passed on to your insert routine. You said that the date is always the same, so there must be some point where you would expect to see two different dates, but the debugger will be showing the same date twice. If you can find the earliest point where that happens that should lead you to the bug.